# Can't preview Github pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to build a github-pages site and to preview it offline. However, I have only partial success, while the page I get served comes from my offline sources, all its resources (css/img) and links point to the github location of the site.

I use [`{{ site.github.url }}`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/), installed jekyll as described [here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/).

I tried `bundle exec jekyll clean`, and attempted to `git remote remove origin` and to unset `github_username`. However, without the remote the site would not build and with it (without a username), it still knew my username as it still generated links to `<username>.github.io/repo/` rather than `127.0.0.1:3000` (I changed the port).

**How can I test my github pages offline properly (i.e. have the links point to my local jekyll instance)?**

Important: When I fire up `bundle exec jekyll serve` I get the following warning:

> GitHub Metadata: No GitHub API authentication could be found. Some fields  > may be missing or have incorrect data.

As far as I am aware this comes from `jekyll-github-metadata` which populates `site.github`. And as such (I assume) `site.github.url`. However, I have not found if this caches data, and how to wipe this data. As I am trying to build an offline test I do want this url to be empty/ point to localhost.

===============================

Header layout excerpt:

```
<head>
<title>A title</a>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.github.url }}/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
```

As this `<head>` section/this layout is used in different parts of the page hierarchy, I need an absolute path to link to the css file.

Comment: `{{ site.github.url }}` is a reference to your github repository url and has nothing to do with your folder hierarchy. It's not supposed to be used to describe links urls. Can you please provide a repository url ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel: given the example I linked to (https://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/) I understood the documentation so that I was supposed to use exactly that, to ensure that if I need to include "myfancy.css" with an absolute path, that it always points to the base. As I use my layout for blogposts, etc., I don't see how I could use relative paths.

Comment: @DavidJacquel: If possible, I would prefer to keep my github and my stackoverflow account seperate for the moment, however I am happy to post excerpts. I will add the header I use in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

Replace : `{{ site.github.url }}/css/bootstrap.min.css`

by : `{{ site.baseurl }}/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Github metadata plugin provides common repository information and is not supposed to be used to generate your resources urls. I don't even see it mentioned in the [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/) you're referencing.

You don't need it to have Jekyll working locally.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and report back/accept. For reference, I was speaking about https://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/#project-page-url-structure.

Comment: Unfortunatly that does not work. Github adds a repository path, that this ommitts. While offline testing works with this, it breaks when I put it up on github.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you are still experiencing this issue, I have a [blog post](http://knightcodes.com/miscellaneous/2016/09/13/fix-github-metadata-error.html) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bQqkyvH5ps) showing how to fix it. The skinny of it is this:

1. Create a personal access token in GitHub. This takes just a second, see [GitHub’s documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/). When picking the scope(s) that you want to grant to the token, just select the repo checkbox.
2. Add a new system environment variable on your machine named JEKYLL_GITHUB_TOKEN and set the value equal to the personal access token you generated.
3. [Go here](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem), copy all the text in the page, and save it as a file named cacert.pem somewhere on your local machine.
4. Add a new system environment variable on your machine named SSL_CERT_FILE and set the value equal to the full file path of where you saved the cacert.pem file.
5. **RESTART YOUR MACHINE** (this is **not** optional)

The blog post assumes you are on a Windows machine, but the same steps should work on a Mac.